# Cron unable to execute a command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I have a script which should run scoutsuite for AWS audit weekly. I am trying to execute the script from cron.
Scoutsuite after running create a folder and saves all the results to a directory "scoutsuite-report".
If I run the script manually, it works perfectly but when placed in a crontab it "scout" command is skipped or rather does not create a directory but rest of the script works.

Script Below:

```
#!/bin/bash


rm -rf /root/scoutsuite-report
rm -f /root/scout*.zip
date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)


scout aws --profile personal --region us-east-1 --no-browser --quiet
sleep 10

# Zip the results with Date

zip -qq -r scout-$date.zip /root/scoutsuite-report
sleep 5

# Mount Space folder | Copy zipped results | Unmount Space folder
mount -t cifs -o credentials=~/.smbcredentials "//<space share>" /media/NAS
cp /root/scout-*.zip /media/NAS/
sleep 60
umount /media/NAS/
```

Crontab Below:

```
0 6 * * MON /root/scripts/scoutsuite.sh
```

Comment: How is this added to crontab?  Is this in the `root` user's crontab?

Comment: Try redirecting output from the script to a file by adding `> /root(scoutsuite.log 2>&1` at the end of the line in crontab. Please also verify what users crontab that run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have no PATH defined when you run the script from cron so try adding the whole path to the command.

e.g. /usr/sbin/scout etc what ever the right path for the command would be

Comment: Thank you very much!
This did the trick..